# remove empty space in the beginning and at the end textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, textarea

so I'm doing a code that basically removes empty lines, as well as remove empty spaces in the beginning of the string and at the end. However `trim` function seems that it doesn't work how can i fix that?

that's the code that i have tried

```
<textarea id="a">
 a

 b
 c   
</textarea><button id="c">Remove blank lines</button><textarea id="b"></textarea>
```

And the jQuery code is:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#c").on("click", function () {
        var avalue = $.trim($('#a').val());
        var newVal = avalue.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, '');
        $('#a').val(newVal);

    });
})
```

Comment: I don't know my way around jquery, but probably it uses `trim` in the same way JS does.
Looking at your code I believe you are putting the string value inside the trim method, but for JS it would be called on the string obj (str.trim()).

Maybe `var avalue = $('#a').val().trim();` will do the job?

Comment: `trim` working perfect .please check first and last letter https://jsfiddle.net/6cagdsme/

Answer (score 1):

Trim() is made for this purpose it removes whitespace in the beginning and end of your string

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#c").on("click", function () {
        var avalue = $.trim($('#a').val());
        var newVal = avalue.trim();
        $('#a').val(newVal);

    });
})
```

Comment: you took off the function that delete the empty lines, i want to delete the empty lines and spaces as well both

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim, it will remove all the spaces around (left or right). The spaces in between will be preserved.

`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myStr = $(".original").text();
        var trimStr = $.trim(myStr);
        $(".trimmed").html(trimStr);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Original String</h3>
    <pre class="original">      Paragraph of text with       multiple    white   spaces before and after.       </pre>
    <br>
    <h3>Trimmed String</h3>
    <pre class="trimmed"></pre>
</body>
```

`

Comment: you took off the function that delete the empty lines, i want to delete the empty lines and spaces as well both

Comment: you mean spaces from within the sentences as well? Like you dont want 

How Are You.... but instead you require HowAreYou?

Comment: If that is the case you can split the trimmed string on spaces " " which will get you array of the words and then join the result (chaining). So trimStr.split(' ').join();

Let me know if this is your requirement, I will update the answer and add these lines as well. Thanks :)